# Can not install open cv on my pycharm version (MAC)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, opencv, pycharm

I used to use anaconda, but currently I tried Pycharm and then I fall in love with it.

Now I have a project from my master degree, one of the module I have to use, is opencv.

But sadly I can't install open cv on my Mac machine correctly,

it keep returned me, this error

Collecting opencv

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv

Comment: How are you installing openCV currently?

Comment: I followed this tutorial I found:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vIA1g9Se_yylg1-ua5JYC7sMxSx4AdRxdZTUKtR_f6U/edit?usp=sharing

everything was just fine, I think I screwed my mac setting on Step 4A, by creating symlinks. Hahaha, I don't understand about creating symlinks. silly me. Do you know how to revert my symlinks?

Comment: *until I think I screwed my mac setting on step 4a. 

Do you know how to delete or undo my symlinks? hahaha

Comment: *How to delete my symlinks* -- is it a serious question? Just go to the directory: `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and delete those files: `rm cv.py cv2.so`.

Comment: @QuangHoang yes it is! Hahaha, silly me. Thanks man! it is working! hahaha. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @RickM. do you know how to install i correctly?

Comment: @BriantStevanus Yes, I will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For installing OpenCV on Mac and using it in PyCharm, follow these steps:

Prerequisites: Python 2.7 or 3xx, [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [OpenCV](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) installed.

Open a terminal and create a virtual environment, `pyimagesearch` here

1. `$ mkvirtualenv pyimagesearch`

Step 2 is miscellaneous, depending on your needs.

2. `pip install numpy`

   `pip install scipy`

   `pip install matplotlib`
3. Sym-link your cv2.so and cv.py files. (only cv2.so files for OpenCV 3xx ).
   On my system, OpenCV is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python/2.7/site_packages/`

   `$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/pyimagesearch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

   `$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py`

   `$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so`
4. These steps are essentially for setting up this virtual environment for PyCharm.

Open up PyCharm and create a new "Pure Python" project

Set up the location of our Python Interpreter. By default, PyCharm will point to the system install of Python, however, for our case we need it to point to the virtual environment `pyimagesearch`.

So click on the gear icon and select "Add Local". In my case, the `pyimagesearch`  virtual environment is located in  `~/.virtualenvs/pyimagesearch/` with the actual Python binary in  `~/.virtualenvs/pyimagesearch/bin`. Once you have successfully navigated to your folder, choose the virtual environment binary which is `python2.7` in the bin folder for me.

Hope it helps!

After this, you are all set. PyCharm will use your `pyimagesearch` virtual environment and will recognize the OpenCV library.

Comment: thanks, but still I can't install certain package. in pycharm even though already made virtual environment, @Rick M. do you know how to restore settings to default in mac? in particular anything with python. haha. thank you in advance Rick

Comment: Which package in particular?

Comment: opencv and python 3.6, Rick.

Comment: Which opencv version?

Comment: opencv2 and opencv3, so I can re install it with another guide I found in pyimagesearch.com @Rick M